# jQuery - How to count the number of hidden or visible rows in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery that counts the number of rows in my table. However, some of the table rows might be hidden because of a filter I have in place. How can I change the function below to count the number of visible rows only?

```
function UpdateCount() {
    var totalRows = $('#listingTable tbody tr').length;
    $("#rowCount").text(totalRows.toString() + " sightings")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:visible` if they are truly hidden, not just without visibility

```
function UpdateCount() {
    var totalRows = $('#listingTable tbody tr:visible').length;
    $("#rowCount").text(totalRows + " sightings");
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly and simple.

Comment: Just note that jQuery defines hidden elements as elements that don't take up space, so `visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0` is still a visible element, while `display:none` is hidden etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)** selector:

> Selects all elements that are visible.

```
function UpdateCount() {
    var totalRows = $('#listingTable tbody tr:visible').length;
    $("#rowCount").text(totalRows.toString() + " sightings")
}
```